# Keep execution of bash script when aborted via CTRL+X or CTRL+C

Tags: linux, bash, terminal

This is very nooby question I belive and I've tried everything to avoid asking it here, but I didn't found answere anywhere on whole internet.

Go on and give me downvote but please answer me **how to keep execution of long-time-running-required bash script when aborted via CTRL+X or CTRL+C?**

- I want to execute command `$ sh myscript.sh` and to free up my terminal by CTRL+X / CTRL+C, script should continue to run next 10-20 min as required.
- I want to execute php script like `$ php /path/to/myphpscript.php` and to free up my terminal by CTRL+X / CTRL+C, script should continue to run next 2 hours as required.

How to have that?

Cronjob is not my solution.

Comment: Why not appending `&` to run it in the background? This will automatically release your terminal!

Comment: @Khaled and how? Please explain me in example `$ php /path/to/myphpscript.php`

Comment: You can 'free up' your terminal by running tmux, to have multiple windows and split panes, etc.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Once your **terminate a job** with <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> it is terminated and you can't tell a dead job to continue and pick up where it was.

The correct term is to run a job in the background, which you can do beforehand:

```
 ./script &
```

You can use that in combination with `nohup` to make the process immune to hang-ups, it will continue to run even if you log out from your bash session:

```
 nohup ./script &
```

If the script is already running you can **suspend a foreground job** with <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> and instruct it to continue in the background with `bg`

There's much more in the  chapter on [job control](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Job-Control.html#Job-Control)  from the bash manual.

Comment: Note that backgrounding a task using `bg` does not prevent it from being killed by logging out/closing that terminal: to do that, do a `disown -h %1` (where 1 is the job id).

Answer (score 1):

You can use screen utility. from man page:

> DESCRIPTION
>          Screen  is a full-screen window manager that multiplexes a physical terminal between several processes (typically interactive
>   shells).